# POSTGRESQL How do I insert the rows of a child table into an array in the parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 related tables: questions and answers

**Questions**

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT,
    answer_ids INTEGER[]
);
```

**Answers**

```
CREATE TABLE answers (
    answer_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id INTEGER
        REFERENCES questions,
    body TEXT
);
```

**Current implementation:**

When a row is added to the answers table, I am pushing the `answer_id` of the answer to the `answer_ids` array of the questions table in the appropriate row. i.e.

If an answer of `answer_id = 5` to the question of `id = 1` is added. I would do something like

```
UPDATE questions SET answer_ids = ARRAY_APPEND(answer_ids, 5) WHERE id = 1;
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I am not necessarily looking for a way to add the answers into the questions table as I feel that would be redundant, what would be the point of having the answers table then?

I am looking for a query that allows me to get a question but instead of getting an array of `answer_ids`, I want an array of the `answers` themselves instead. So the query would return something like this in JSON:

```
{ id: 1,
  title: 'title of question 1',
  answers: [{ answer_id: 1,
              question_id: 1,
              body: 'body of answer 1'},
            { answer_id: 3,
              question_id: 1,
              body: 'body of answer 3'}]
}
```

Comment: You already have `question_id` in the `answers` table. Is there any special purpose to also have `answer_ids` in the `questions` table?

Comment: I have `answer_ids` in the questions table, cause I wanted to be able to get a question with it's answers in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

May be  this? ([here are functions for work with json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html))

```
WITH Questions(id, title) as (
    select 1, 'title 1' union all
    select 2, 'title 2' 
),
Answers(answer_id, question_id, body) as (
    select 1, 1, 'body of answer 1' union all
    select 3, 1, 'body of answer 3'  union all
    select 4, 2, 'body of answer 4'  
)

SELECT json_build_object('id',id, 'title',title, 'answers', 
    (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('answer_id',answer_id,'question_id',question_id,'body',body)) FROM Answers WHERE Answers.question_id = Questions.id) ) 
from Questions 
WHERE Questions.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a type for a n answer.

```
CREATE TYPE answer_t
            AS (answer_id integer,
                question_id integer,
                body text);
```

And then lateral cross join the `answer_id`s to the questions and use them to inner join the answers. Now aggregate and use `array_agg()` to get an array of answers for each question.

```
SELECT q.*,
       array_agg((a.answer_id,
                  a.question_id,
                  a.body)::answer_t) answers
       FROM questions q
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(q.answer_ids) un(answer_id)
            INNER JOIN answers a
                       ON a.answer_id = un.answer_id
       GROUP BY q.id;
```

But note, your data design is horrible and should be revised. Values, that reference other records should never be put in arrays. Referential integrity cannot be enforced or only with very inefficient triggers, if they are in arrays. Use a linking table. Then you can also drop that back referencing column `question_id` in `answers`.